# Writing a response body to a file with CURL

Tags: php, curl

I want to write a retrieved page to a file with CURL, and I have written a code. The problem is it works with my system IP, but when I set CURLOPT_PROXY to a proxy, the code runs but not writing anything to the file, returning an empty file. I cannot figure out the problem, and I need your help.

```
 <?php


  $header_array[] = "Mime-Version: 1.0";
  $header_array[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
  $header_array[] = "Accept-Encoding: compress, gzip";



  $fh = fopen('example.txt','w+') or die($php_errormsg);
  $c = curl_init('http://example.com/');
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_PROXY, '198.136.50.131:7808');
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_array);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
  curl_exec($c);
  curl_close($c);
?>
```

Comment: What happens when you try to access the resource through your proxy by some means other than PHP curl?

Comment: I have not tried it. Do you sense it is a proxy problem?

Comment: Never hurts to rule such things out.